# Как эффективно объединить 2 DataFrame с добавлением результата вычислений в новую колонку только для строк по условию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Есть два DataFrame с временными затратами за день и на отдельные задачи:

```py
d = [('20190601', 7.0), ('20190602', 8.0)]
t = [('20190601', 'task1', 5.0), ('20190601', 'task2', 1.0), ('20190602', 'task1', 4.0), ('20190602', 'task2', 3.0)]

ddf = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['date', 'fact'])
tdf = pd.DataFrame(t, columns=['date', 'task', 'fact'])
```

Подсчитываю сумму времнных затрат всех задач за день:

```
sumdf = tdf.groupby([tdf.date]).fact.sum().reset_index()

       date  fact
0  20190601   6.0
1  20190602   7.0
```

Потом пытаюсь объединить в конечный DataFrame:

```
df = pd.concat([ddf, tdf], axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
df.sort_values(['date', 'task'], na_position='first', inplace=True)

       date  fact   task
0  20190601   7.0    NaN
2  20190601   5.0  task1
3  20190601   1.0  task2
1  20190602   8.0    NaN
4  20190602   4.0  task1
5  20190602   3.0  task2
```

Но не совсем понимаю, как лучше добавить также и суммы из `sumdf`, чтобы получилось:

```
       date  fact   task  calc
0  20190601   7.0    NaN   6.0
2  20190601   5.0  task1   NaN
3  20190601   1.0  task2   NaN
1  20190602   8.0    NaN   7.0
4  20190602   4.0  task1   NaN
5  20190602   3.0  task2   NaN
```

То есть, суммы за день должны оказаться в новой колонке `calc` только для строк где `task=NaN`.

Как выполнить такое объединение наиболее эффективно? По возможности, без промежуточного подсчета сумм за день.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
res = (pd.concat((tdf, 
                  ddf.merge(tdf.groupby("date")
                               ["fact"]
                               .sum()
                               .reset_index(name="calc"), 
                            on="date")), 
                 ignore_index=True, 
                 sort=False)
         .sort_values(['date', 'task'], 
                      na_position='first'))
```

результат:

```
In [33]: res
Out[33]:
       date   task  fact  calc
4  20190601    NaN   7.0   6.0
0  20190601  task1   5.0   NaN
1  20190601  task2   1.0   NaN
5  20190602    NaN   8.0   7.0
2  20190602  task1   4.0   NaN
3  20190602  task2   3.0   NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Мне потребуется немного времени, чтобы проверить.

Comment: Отлично, работает, не ожидал, что все так просто. Спасибо.

Comment: @V_somnenii, пожалуйста. Тут вся "фишка" в том чтобы собрать ответ из простых действий в правильном порядке

Comment: Да, мне это известно, но где то накосячил, с порядком наверное. Еще раз спасибо, упвоут пока не получается, т.к. репутации мало.

Answer (score 2):

Сначала выделяем строки из `df`, которым нужно подставить значение:

```py
temp1 = df.loc[df['task'].isna()]
```

Затем достаём нужные значения из `sumdf`:

```py
temp2 = temp1.merge(sumdf, on='date', how='left', indicator=True)
```

Остаётся лишь создать новый столбец:

```py
df['calc'] = np.NaN
```

И подставить полученные значения в нужных местах:

```py
df.loc[df['task'].isna(), 'calc'] = temp2['fact_y']
```

Результат:

```
    date    fact    task    calc
0   20190601    7.0 NaN     6.0
2   20190601    5.0 task1   NaN
3   20190601    1.0 task2   NaN
1   20190602    8.0 NaN     7.0
4   20190602    4.0 task1   NaN
5   20190602    3.0 task2   NaN
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Провериил, работает как ожидалось.

Comment: @V_somnenii на этом сайте благодарность выражают стрелкой вверх и галочкой принятого ответа `;)`

Comment: Да, я доогадываюсь. Для стрелочки наверх, говорит, что у меня мало репутации. А для галочки мне надо немного времени, попробовать решения из других ответов.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо, решение в любом случае интерессное и заслуживает внимания.